# Select home directory dialog can't select a directory

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to select a new home directory for JDK, as I want to use a newer JDK. However, when selecting NEW -> JDK in the Project SDK settings, a Windows XP style dialog opens up, in which I can only select files and not directories. When I select an arbitrary file in the directory I really want to select, nothing happens.

This is the dialog I get:
[image: dialog]

This also applies to other projects, I have already invalidated my Caches and I'm sure it has worked once upon a time. This is the result I receive from "About":

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
Licensed to DPS Engineering GmbH / Timo Borner
You have a perpetual fallback license for this version
Subscription is active until June 18, 2020
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Note that I have the same post on the [IntelliJ support forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004319039-Select-home-directory-dialog-can-t-select-a-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the file `ide.general.xml` solves the issue. It is not an elegant solution, because this seems to be a bug on the side of IntelliJ (see [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218339) ticket).

The problem is, that when syncing settings via the settings repository on Linux and Windows, weird things happen.